# Changing Background color every time you open the Android app

Tags: android

I'm very new to android programming world and i have a problem:

I made a simply app that basically change the color of the background and the color of a button when you open it (i've tried using a switch with some color set in res), but it doesn't work and every time i open it there is the same color.

This is my activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RelativeLayout v;
Button z;
Random r;
int randomNumber;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    v=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
    z=(Button) findViewById(R.id.mainButton);

    r=new Random();
    randomNumber=r.nextInt(10);


    switch (randomNumber)
    {
        case 0: v.setBackgroundColor(R.color.indigo);  z.setBackgroundColor(R.color.indigoB); break;
        case 1: v.setBackgroundColor(R.color.deepOrange);  z.setBackgroundColor(R.color.deepOrangeB); break;
        case 2: v.setBackgroundColor(R.color.purple);  z.setBackgroundColor(R.color.purpleB); break;
        case 3: v.setBackgroundColor(R.color.blueGrey);  z.setBackgroundColor(R.color.blueGreyB); break;
        case 4: v.setBackgroundColor(R.color.red);  z.setBackgroundColor(R.color.redB); break;
        case 5: v.setBackgroundColor(R.color.green);  z.setBackgroundColor(R.color.greenB); break;
        case 6: v.setBackgroundColor(R.color.lime);  z.setBackgroundColor(R.color.limeB); break;
        case 7: v.setBackgroundColor(R.color.pink);  z.setBackgroundColor(R.color.pinkB); break;
        case 8: v.setBackgroundColor(R.color.yellow);  z.setBackgroundColor(R.color.yellowB); break;
        case 9: v.setBackgroundColor(R.color.teal);  z.setBackgroundColor(R.color.tealB); break;
        case 10:v.setBackgroundColor(R.color.deepPurple);  z.setBackgroundColor(R.color.deepPurpleB); break;
    }



}
```

};

why this doesn't work?
And anyone know a solution for this problem?

thanks for help.

Comment: What you're probably missing here, is an understanding of the [Android activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html). Your activity is not recreated unless the activity is finished or an (unhandled) configuration change occurs.

Comment: Yes, but also with all onStart, onResume, onPause, onStop, onDestroy  it didn't work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`setBackgroundColor()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundColor(int)) accepts a color integer (`@ColorInt`), not a color resource ID (`@ColorRes`). You should pass a color *value* instead of a resource reference.

In short, replace:

```
v.setBackgroundColor(R.color.indigo);
```

with:

```
v.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.indigo));
```

If you're referencing this view from outside of a context, you will need to obtain the Resources instance from context.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works fine but i see that the getColor() method require API 23 or superior, Do you know other way to do the same thing?

Comment: @Andrea You can conditionally use the [API level 1](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getColor%28int%29) or [API level 23 method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getColor%28int,%20android.content.res.Resources.Theme%29), but if you're using the support library, I recommend using [ContextCompat's method instead](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/ContextCompat.html#getColor%28android.content.Context,%20int%29).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 private final int colorArray[] = {
        R.color.indigo, R.color.deepOrange, R.color.purple,R.color.blueGrey
     };
```

**Add this method to shuffle colors:**

```
static void shuffleArray(int[] arr)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            int index = rnd.nextInt(i + 1);
            // Swap
            int a = arr[index];
            arr[index] = arr[i];
            arr[i] = a;
        }
    }
```

**Call the shuffle method in `onCreate()` and pass your color array as an argument:**

```
shuffleArray(imageArray)
```

Then use:

```
v.setBackgroundColor(colorArray[0]);  
z.setBackgroundColor(colorArray[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this function

```
public int newRandom(){
   Random r;
   r=new Random();
   return  r.nextInt(10);
}
```

On the OnCreate put

```
randomNumber = newRandom();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the code to change color in `onResume` rather than in `onCreate` event like:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
   super.onResume();
   // add code to change color here
}
```

Because there is a possiblity that the app is not actually closed and just minimized; and when you tap the icon to open the app, it just maxmize the app which triggeres the `onResume` event rather than `onCreate`; that's why the color is not changing is because the `onCreate` event is not triggered.